# hasOne and belongsTo relation tables in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

my tables :

users :

```
id fname email
```

brands:

```
id title user_id_made
```

each brand has a `user_id_made` that is a `foreign key` of `users` table.

in `Brand` model :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User','id');
}
```

in User model:

```
public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Brand','user_id_made');
}
```

I have a list of brands like this :

```
title of brand       -   email of user that made it
```

in my controller I write this code :

```
$data['brands']  = Brand::with('user')->simplePaginate(2);
```

in `foreach` of view I got  `trying to get non-object property` error :

```
            @foreach($brands as $brand)



                <tr>
                 <td>{{$brand->title_fa}}</td>
                 <td>{{$brand->title_en}}</td>
                 <td>{{$brand->user->fname}}</td> // error line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give the brand title and email of the user with this brand.

```
$brands=Brand::with('user')->get();
foreach($brands as $brand)
{
    print_r($brand->title);
    print_r($brand->user->email);
}
```

The relation in Brand Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User','user_id_made');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong relationship. `hasOne` is used on one-to-one relationships but it should be a one-to-many relationship between your `Brand` and `User`. (Each brand is made by one user and each user can make more than one brand)

If you state that a `Brand` `hasOne` `User`, Laravel will assume the `users` table having a foreign key referencing the `brands` table.

Instead, modify your relationship method to use `belongsTo`.

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id_made');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Brand model has the foreign key, this is the side that the 
`belongsTo()` method should be.

If you used the convention when naming your foreign key `user_id` things would 
be more straight forward.

But if for whatever reason you need to have `user_id_made` name for the column,

this is what you should pass as a second argument in both sides of the relationship.

The `User` should have the `hasOne('App\Brand', 'user_id_made')`.

And the `Brand` should have `belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id_made')`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships